# How do I get RVM tied to a directory/project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm using rvm with rails at work and when I cd into our project directory it automatically sets the gemset. I remember the first time I went into that directory I was asked if I wanted to use the specified gemset and of course I agreed, and from then on it just gets set. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
-( codemonkey )-(~/maintenance)-
-(0)> go
/home/webpath/maintenance
Using /home/webpath/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136 with gemset webpath
-( codemonkey )-(~/maintenance)-
-(0)>
```

Now, I've been "practicing" installing and setting up RVM & Rails at home so that I can do it in my sleep (in case I move on to another RoR job and want to use RVM), but for the life of me I can't get the above behavior. I have to cd into the project directory and then:

```
-( me )-(~/project)-
-(0)> rvm use 1.9.2@myproject
```

Before anyone beats up on me, the guy who originally got us on RVM left the company and I am trying to fill the void he left but this is a bit O' goo I can't figure out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To tie a particular Ruby to a directory, drop a `.rvmrc` file into that directory. You can then select the ruby version and gemset as follows.

```
rvm use 1.9.2@myproject
```

Leave the directory then re-enter it, you'll be asked to confirm the RVM selection as you described in your question.

Full documentation: http://beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/

Comment: Perfect. This was the goo I was missing. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

It isn't remembering the last used set on the directory, it's loading the gemset from the `.rvmrc` file in that directory

https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/

Answer (score 0):

This is a nicer way to have your .rvmrc file (from one of my projects):

```
if [[ -d "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments" \
  && -s "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/ruby-1.8.6-p399@elearning" ]] ; then
  \. "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/ruby-1.8.6-p399@elearning"
else
  rvm --create  "ruby-1.8.6-p399@elearning"
fi
```

This will create the gemset if it doesn't already exist, then switch to it.  It looks complicated but it's actually what rvm will set up for you if you ask it to create a .rvmrc file for you when you make a new gemset:

```
rvm --create --rvmrc 1.8.6@project
```